# How do I add a filter to a background image in the body

Tags: css

I am trying to add a filter to the background image of the body.
I currently am using this code:

```css
body {
    background: url("/img/congruent_pentagon.png");
    color: white;
    font-family: "Raleway";
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(1);
}
```

It is making all of the child elements in grayscale but not the background image itself. I have looked into what others have done and it's mainly people manipulating html elements. That is not what I'm trying to achieve. Is it even possible to add a filter in this way? If so, how?

Comment: Can you create an example of this in codepen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just **too much work** compared to **using Photoshop** or something similar to desaturate the image.

With that being said....
You can use `pseudo-element` selectors for that. in my case I added the background to the `pseudo-element` `:before`

I then made sure it's sized correctly and added a **negative** `z-index` so that it *always renders behind the content* of the body and not on top.

Then I applied the filter to it.

I believe this is what you wanted.

```css
body {
margin: 0 auto;
}

body:before {
  background: url("https://unsplash.it/1920/?image=1062") no-repeat center;
  background-size: 100%;
  content: "";
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  position: fixed;
  filter: grayscale(1);
  z-index: -1;

}

.content {
  opacity: .6;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 1em;
}

/* color fluff */
.aa {background: yellow;}
.bb {background: red;}
.cc {background: green;}
.dd {background: orange;}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content aa"></div>
  <div class="content bb"></div>
  <div class="content cc"></div>
  <div class="content dd"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's not a "pseudo-**class**"...it's a pseudo-**element**.

Comment: Thanks @Paulie_D I will fix it now :)

Comment: Thank you! yes, it does seem like too much work. My buddy was saying that we must really be lazy if we didn't want to take 30 seconds to do it in photoshop.

Comment: @VictorA. You're welcome. Yeah I agree. Editing the photo is a much better choice for this. Thank you!